# How does std::unordered_map determine the location of a specific key in a hash table?

Tags: c++, hash, hashtable, unordered-map

The documentation mentions that `std::unordered_map` uses a hash table. How does it achieve O(1) lookup of a specific key in the hash table? The only way I can think of is to store each key at an address computed from the hash value of the data it holds. If this is the case, how does it keep all of the keys close together in memory such that it does not get used up quickly? Furthermore, what if more than one `std::unordered_map` is used? How does the implementation guarantee that no two maps will ever compute hashes that boil down to the same address?

Comment: Basically, with fixed array size, `arr[hash(key) % arr.size()]` is `O(1)` (collisions indeed increases worst case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically a hash map keeps an array of buckets inside. A bucket, on the other hand is a list of entries. And so something like this:

```cpp
template<class TKey, class TValue>
class HashMap {
    vector<vector<pair<TKey, TValue>>> Buckets;
};
```

Then when you do a lookup, it simply takes the key, computes its hash, say `hash`, goes to `Buckets[hash % Buckets.size]`, which is of type `vector<pair<TKey,TValue>>` and does a linear search on it. This makes the **amortized** (average) lookup complexity constant, while in the worst case (e.g. bad hashing function) it is linear. And indeed, this is the guarantee you get with the unordered_map.

Note that the top level vector will eventually grow when you add elements (maybe even when you remove), in order to allow more entries and avoid collisions. Rehashing is likely to take place in such case. And so adding/removing elements is not trivial, and can be expensive from time to time.

Also note that since `vector` allocates memory on the heap under the hood, then there is no issue with using more than one map. They share nothing (well, they may share something, but it doesn't affect the behaviour). But even if an implementation does not use `vector` (which is not mandatory, its just an example), some form of dynamic `malloc` has to be used to guarantee that.

Comment: What guarantees that they share nothing? Two of their keys can hash down to the same spot in memory.

Comment: @WaisKamal typically hashes do not produce addresses in memory. At least not absolute, but rather relative to the hashmap. Hashes point to the appropriate index in the internal array (see `Buckets[hash % Buckets.size]` line). For an element to appear in the internal array it has to be copied there from the outside of course. Each hashmap keeps its own internal array (and so its own copy of value), they do not share anything. Well, to be 100% correct they may share something, its an implementation detail after all, but whatever happens under the hood thats how it looks from user's perspective.

Comment: There is no guarantee that they "share nothing".   However, the implementation details are hidden away behind `unordered_map`s interface (set of functions that act on the map - modifying, looking up, etc) and there is no way within standard C++ to determine if instances `unordered_map`s share data among themselves.  Practically, implementing `unordered_map` so data is shared somehow among distinct instances would be complicated e.g. whenever one instance that is sharing data is destroyed, it would be necessary to ensure data seen by other instances remains consistent.

Comment: @freakish fair point, but I have one more question: you mention that "*adding/removing elements is not trivial, and can be expensive from time to time*". But the way you have shown suggests that whenever an element is added or removed, all addresses have to be recomputed (because `Buckets.size` would've changed. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @WaisKamal it is not always the case that `Buckets.size` changes when an element is added/removed. Typically a hash map will allocate say 100 buckets up front and when a certain threshold (either current size or myabe number of collisions, its an implementation detail) is reached, it will increase its capacity say x2 and recompute everything. This is similar to how vector resize works. And of course requires some additional data to be stored, i.e. a flag that the bucket is in use, not just pending for usage.

Comment: @WaisKamal Note that this is not the only possible strategy. I encourage you to read this wiki entry thoroughly: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table especially "Dynamic resizing" piece.

Comment: Ok thank you very much, this was indeed helpful.

Answer (score 4):

`O(1)` does not mean that the algorithm's complexity is "one shot", or, in this case, a value in the map must be retrieved with a single lookup, of some sort, based on its key.

`O(1)` really means `O(amortized constant)`, that is: it takes a constant amount of time to complete, ***on average***.

One possible implementation for an unordered map would be a hash table containing a linked list of all values that have the same hash key, and the unordered map dynamically adjusts the size of the hash table, as needed. It is entirely possible that an occasional map look up will have to search a small linked list to find the right hash key. Also, occasionally, an insert or delete operation will take an additional amount of time to rehash the entire unordered map.

If you look up the details of unordered maps' methods in your reference material you will find it explicitly mentioned that all existing to an unordered map get invalidated if a modification triggers a rehash.

But, ***on average***, an unordered map lookup is expected to take a constant amount of time.

Comment: I think the "on average"  part is wrong here. `std::vector::push_back` is on average O(1), and that is specifically allowed by the standard. I think you get a true O(1) lookup by limiting each hash bucket size to a fixed constant. Walking a linked list of 100 items max is still O(1). Now insertions are another matter; those can trigger rehashes and therefore would be a worst-case O(N) complexity. But that's not the question here.

Comment: @MSalters you cannot limit each bucket's size to a fixed constant. If someone passes a bad hashing function to such map, e.g. a hashing function that always returns the same value, then your map is simply a vector now. And so it can grow arbitrarily large. Unless there's some fancy mechanism to deal with that, that I'm not aware of.

Comment: @MSalters "[Complexity](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/find#Complexity): Constant on average, worst case linear in the size of the container."

Comment: I do understand how a single unordered_map resolves hash collisions within its elements. My question is how does it do this using a small amount of memory, and how does it guarantee that no two keys **that belong to different maps** will end up in the same spot in the hash table? In other words, how do two maps avoid rehashing as much as possible, and when they come up with the new hashes, what makes them certain that the new hashes do not also collide somewhere?

Comment: What do you mean by "two keys that belong to different maps"? Each map has its own set of keys that are not shared with any other map. Each unordered map has its own dedicated hash table. If the same key is added to different maps, each one of these maps places the same key in the same hash table.

Comment: "*If the same key is added to different maps, each one of these maps places the same key in the **same hash table***" this way the map will malfunction.

Comment: I mistyped. Is it clear that each map has its own hash table?

Comment: Yes, all clear now. Thank you!